# java convert hex to ascii - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hexBinary needs to be even-length

Tags: java, hex, ascii, converters

I'm trying to convert a hex message to ascii 
and I don't understand why I get this error

```
String final = (msg1 + " " + msg2 + " " + msg3);
byte[] s = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(final);
String final = new String(s);
```

and this is the error I get :(the data is correct )

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hexBinary needs to be even-length: 4C 4B 4C 41 36 4C 31 45 32 48 41 37 32 32 31 36 31 FF
```

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the spaces from your input String.

Comment: You cannot name a variable `final` this is a keyword

Comment: @Eran    OK - so it will a long row? 4c4b4c41......?

Comment: Additionally: using `new String(byte[])` is a terrible idea, you should **really** specify an encoding when you do that, or you'll use the platform default which is almost certainly a bad idea (you might get away with it on Android, since there the platform default is always UTF-8, but you should still specify that explicitly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parseHexBinary` is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary(java.lang.String)) to take the input as defined by [`xsd:hexBinary`](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77143.html).

This means the input string must contain **only** hexadecimal characters and always pairs. Your input stream contains space characters, that must be removed prior to parsing.

```
input = input.replaceAll(" +", "");
```

Comment: I didn't know this.... thanks  ,  -  but I need the " + ", whouldn't " " will be good?